# Error when mapping a Props from A to B Component Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.cate.map)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hello and Good Day Everyone. I am newbie to react world and I am practicing and building an Food App UI and now, I am trying to map the category props which is a state in my Home category and I pass it through props now I am trying to map it in my product component.

**Home Component Code**

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null)
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantData)
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(initialCurrentLocation)

function onSelectedCategory(Category){
    let restaurantList = restaurantData.filter(a => a.categories.includes
    (Category.id))
    
    setRestaurants(restaurantList)
    setSelectedCategory(Category)
}

function getCategoryNameById(id) {
    let kategory = categories.filter(a => a.id == id)
    if(kategory.length > 0){
        return kategory[0].name
    }else{
        return ""
    }
}


return (
    <HomeComponentContext.Provider value={{
        selectedCategory
    }}>
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Top name={currentLocation.streetName}/>
        <Categories
            item={categories}
            funct={onSelectedCategory}
            selectcat={selectedCategory}
            />
        <Product 
            item={restaurants}
            func={getCategoryNameById}
            cate = {categories}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
    </HomeComponentContext.Provider>
)
```

**Product Component**

```
                    {
                    item.cate.map((item) => {
                        return(
                            <View 
                            key={item}
                            style={{
                                flexDirection:'row'
                            }}
                            >
                                <Text
                                style={{
                                    ...FONTS.body3
                                }}
                                >
                                    {()=>props.catfunc(item)}
                                </Text>

                                <Text style={{
                                    ...FONTS.h3,
                                }}> .
                               </Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Ok, and what's the issue. please describe so that someone can help

Comment: @Gulam Hussain i got an Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.cate.map') when mapping an props.

Comment: what's `item` in product component, can you please share product component's code?

Comment: @GulamHussain item is a parameter of my function and the item is also a props from home component

Comment: Please share the Product component code, full code, not just the map part of the product component. I think you are messing up `props.item` and `props.cate` variables. but still can't say because you haven't shared the Product component code.

Comment: @GulamHussain Here's my Full code of Product Component. https://codepen.io/saintxcalibur/pen/dyWymbM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234306/discussion-between-gulam-hussain-and-dave).

Comment: In a first glance, you are reusing variable name `item` twice.

`item.cate.map` and `((item) => ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `Product` component you are looping over `item.cate.map` which is throwing an error because `item` is undefined there.

You are passing categories in `cate` props, so to map over categories you need to do `props.cate.map` instead of `item.cate.map`.

And I recommend to use meaningful variable names, `item` is very generic and will create confusion and sometimes very annoying bugs.